# Javascript fade image in and out

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to JavaScript and i need a very simple script to fade an image in and out slowly on a loop. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you can resist to jQuery's sirens songs here is a DOM way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207586

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be using jQuery:

```
<img src="..." id="myImage">


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){

   // Fade In
   $("#myImage").fadeIn();

   // Fade Out
   $("#myImage").fadeOut();

});
</script>
```

Documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

You can also change the fade duration by passing a parameter

```
 // predefined slow (200ms)
 $("#myImage").fadeOut("slow");

 // predefined fast (600ms)
 $("#myImage").fadeOut("fast");

 // 1500 ms
 $("#myImage").fadeOut(1500);
```

---

Update creating a loop:

```
function fadeIn()
{
   $(this).fadeIn( fadeOut );
}

function fadeOut()
{
   $(this).fadeOut( fadeIn );
}

fadeIn.call($("#myImage"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [fadein function in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

```
$('#imgName').fadeIn('slow');
```