# Fading images in javascript game

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am working on Javascript, HTML canvas based game and as I am damaging main boss, his pictures change. I want to ask if its possible to change two pictures in JS with special efect - fading. So far I have not come up with solution.

Here is example of pictures that I want to change with effect.

[image: Example]

My code looks so far like this

```
        if(hp>7 && hp<15) this.boss.srcY = 520;
        if(hp>=15 && hp <22) this.boss.srcY = 680;
        if(hp>=22 && hp <30) this.boss.srcY = 840;
        if(hp>=30 && hp <37) this.boss.srcY = 1000;
        if(hp>=37 && hp <45) this.boss.srcY = 1200;
        if(hp>=45 && hp <50) this.boss.srcY = 1365;
```

Explanation of the code is- More hits (less HP) equals to more damaged picture (5 different pictures). 
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use canvas to create you planes at various stages of fading.

[image]

Use context.globalAlpha to set the opacity of a drawn image.

```
context.globalAlpha=0.50;    // opacity at 50%
context.drawImage(yourPlane,0,0);
```

A performance note: Since drawing pre-existing images is faster than applying an effect and then drawing, you could save your plane as images at various stages of fading.

```
var plane50percent=new Image();
plane50percent.src=canvas.toDataURL();  // image.onload omitted for brevity
```

Then just draw the pre-drawn planes at various stages of fading to get your effect.

Here's code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/v5TwY/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
          return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
          function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
        })();


        var fps = 60;

        // image loader
        var img=new Image();
        img.onload=function(){
            animate();
        }
        img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/b2.png";


        function animate() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                requestAnimFrame(animate);


                // set the current opacity
                ctx.globalAlpha-=.02;

                // draw the image
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                ctx.drawImage(img,5,5);

                if(ctx.globalAlpha<=0){ return; }

            }, 1000 / fps);
        }


    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=405 height=200></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer on another question that seems similar to yours. [Javascript fade image in and out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942727/javascript-fade-image-in-and-out) It's in a loop but I think you can rewrite it to fit your needs.

Comment: I think this would be better as a comment.

Comment: I didn't have enough rep or I would have