# Create a loop for a javascript code

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to create a loop for following js code. Please help me.

```
function fade90() { document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity="0.90"; setTimeout("fade80()", 100); }
function fade80() { document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity="0.80"; setTimeout("fade70()", 100); }
function fade70() { document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity="0.70"; setTimeout("fade60()", 100); }
function fade60() { document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity="0.60"; setTimeout("fade50()", 100); }
function fade50() { document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity="0.50"; setTimeout("fade40()", 100); }
function fade40() { document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity="0.40"; setTimeout("fade30()", 100); }
function fade30() { document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity="0.30"; setTimeout("fade20()", 100); }
function fade20() { document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity="0.20"; setTimeout("fade10()", 100); }
function fade10() { document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity="0.10"; setTimeout("hide()", 100); }
```

I write this. Is this correct? If not please fix this.

```
function cls_msg(){
    for (var i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
    setTimeout(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.opacity=100-(i*10), 100);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why have you tried? [ask]

Comment: @Doorknob you beat me to it :D

Comment: `while (IDoNotUnderstandIt()) { learnJavascript(); }`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060539/javascript-fade-element-from-specidied-opacity-to-specified-opacity

Comment: Is this how you raise the devil with JS?

Comment: @Chris he got -50HP on me in one hit, blowing through my armor, that's for sure...

Comment: @ppeterka Stack Overflow used the common sense approach and flagged the hell out of it. it's super effective!

Comment: I can see why you want a loop.

Comment: @Chris but my faith in humanity... That has went to an all time low. Again... I'm starting to see a trend here...

Comment: Where is the `hide()` function? The whole code will fail at the end, causing your loop to become untied. P.S. This is the least of our worries with this question.

Comment: Wait... you want to call all your  functions at the same time on the same element?

Comment: the most epic code i've seen in a while

Comment: @thesystem Look again, he'll call `fade90` which will eventually trigger all of the others in turn (See the `setTimeout` at the end of each).

Comment: @jdwire: Oh, right. The `setTimeout` is inside. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Before answering your actual question, I provide you a more proper solution to solve your fading issue since you try to do it overly complicated.

You should just modify the actual value and re-assign it to the style, no need to invoke all that methods and re-query the DOM.

```
function fadeIn( node, v ) {
    node.style.opacity = v || 1;

    if( v < 1 ) {
        setTimeout( fadeIn.bind( null, node, v + 0.1 ), 25 );
    }
 }

function fadeOut( node, v ) {
    node.style.opacity = v || 1;

    if( v > 0 ) {
        setTimeout( fadeOut.bind( null, node, v - 0.1 ), 25 );
    }
}
```

This is a pretty basic example of one way to accomplish the task. You can call it like

```
fadeOut( document.getElementById("myDiv") );
```

It's maybe an even better idea to let the browser / *css transitions* do the job, if don't need to support legacy browsers with animations. That could look like

```
function fadeIn( node ) {
    node.style.transition = 'all 400ms ease-in';
    node.style.opacity = 1;
}

function fadeOut( node ) {
    node.style.transition = 'all 400ms ease-in';
    node.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

Be aware that you might want to not just set *transition*, but also all the specific browser vendor prefixes like *-ms-transition*, *-moz-transition*, etc. for "not so legacy" browsers aswell.

---

To finally answer the question, you should use an *Array* to loop over multiple functions, this might look like

```
[ fade90, fade80, fade70, fade60,
  fade50, fade40, fade30, fade20,
  fade10, hide ].forEach(function( method, i, arr ) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          if( typeof arr[ i+1 ] === 'function' ) {
              !i && method();
              setTimeout( arr[ i+1 ], 25 * i );
          }
      }, 25);
});
```

Be aware that you also should re-write those methods also, those should not call `setTimeout` for themselfs, also they should not re-query for the target node. I just wanted to give you an example of my approach.

Comment: +1, elegant, nicely done

Comment: Or you could skip the `.bind()`, and do `setTimeout(fadeIn, 25, node, v + 0.1);` It would need a shim, but then so would `.bind()`. But +1.

Comment: @thesystem: True, I like to forget that `setTimeout` has an implied curry mechanism. But as you mentioned, its not that cross-browser aswell.

Comment: Hmmm... you lost me on the last example. First, you forgot to define `i`, but easy fix. Beyond that, it seems the index `0-8` methods will all be invoked after `25ms`, and then methods `1-9` will all be invoked `25ms` later. So you're invoking most of them twice, and not staggering their invocations. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Perhaps you intended to use an `if/else` for the invocations, and a `* i` for the `setTimeout`s ?

Comment: ...I may just be confused.

Comment: I was wrong about everything being invoked twice. Was turned around on the `!i`, but the timing does need to be staggered. Assuming you just forgot the `* i` and the parameters `, i, arr`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are asking, but may I suggest something a little tidier?

```
function fade(n, el) {
  el.style.opacity = n;
  n = n - 0.1;
  if (n.toFixed(1) > 0) {setTimeout(function() {fade(n, el);},100);}
  else {setTimeout(function() {hide(el);}, 100);}
}

function hide(el) {
  el.style.visibility='hidden';
}
```

and then initially call

```
fade(0.9, document.getElementById("myDiv"));
```

eg: http://jsfiddle.net/XY4yM/

Comment: Change `...hide something?` to `document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility='hidden';`

Comment: Why do you set a timeout on `hide()`? With `opacity == 0` it's not visible anyway, so you can hide it immediately.

Comment: @DanLee The opacity will be 0 the next time. Notice the `n = n - 0.1;` before checking `if (n != 0)`. Opacity is never set to 0.

Comment: Careful. This loop will never end. Floating point arithmetic problem. `n` will never equal `0`.

Comment: @thesystem Then @CJ. should change `if (n != 0)` to something like `if(n > .0001)`?

Comment: Have you been testing your answer? This won't work in its current form.

Comment: @thesystem hadn't, good shout, should be fine now - see fiddle